# CSS chaining performance

Tags: html, css, performance

I don't know if chaining is the right term.
I talk about coding like this:

```
    html > body > div > ul > li > a{
        /*css*/
    }
```

I talked with a friend of mine who told me that coding css like this is giving low perfomance on the browser when rendering the css.
So is this true or I really should declarate only classes/id's and specify on them?

Comment: You should ask him for any proof

Comment: When the scope is more, you will be iterating through many dom elements. A good practice is to use minimum scope such as search by element ID.

Comment: @Johnson - Yep!  He might be a man! ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to apply to an element within a certain element, you can try something like this:

```
#ullID li{ ... }
```

By doing so, you set the styles for the `li` tags within the #ullID element. If you want to go even deeper, you can do it like so:

```
#ullID li a{ ... }
```

I'd say this will be faster performance wise in contrary to using:

```
 html > body > div > ul > li > a{ ... }
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 7):

You should be only as specific as you have to be in order to target your elements.
Using id is preferrable.

Ultimately though -this sort of micro optimisation is fairly irrelevant. Only worth looking at once you have optimised pretty much *everything* else (compressing images, serving of static content, using css sprites, minimising assets etc.)

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/

Comment: +1 for linking to actual test data, rather than wildly speculating like all the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion you should use the least number of selection rules required. The more rules the longer it takes to process.

So yes it is better practice to use classes and IDs.

Also the example you gave above, if you are trying to apply the CSS to all  tags it will work fine with just

```
a {
/* css */
}
```

Comment: This was just an example. Sometimes i have very large css-es and when I'm apllying only to a classes I'm getting a little confused and then I started coding it like this. But lets say that I have 3 ul-s in the page and every one of them has a different style. Is it good to set them ID-s and specify like this #ulID > li and #ulID > li > a?

Answer (score 2):

CSS is read by the browser from right to left, meaning that in your example, the browser would look for all `<a>`, then for the parent `<li>`, until it reaches `<html>`.

So yes for performance, this style of writing styles is bad for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an rough aproximation of selectors optimization:

1. id (#myid)
2. class (.myclass)
3. tag (div, h1, p)
4. List item
5. adjacent sibling (h1 + p)
6. List item child (ul > li)
7. descendent (li a)
8. universal (*)
   9.attribute (a[rel="external"])
9. pseudo-class and pseudo element (a:hover, li:first)

And this are things to keep in mind when where talking aboult SEO. That's doesn't mean that you have to forget about all of them and use only classe and id's.
The thing is that when your saying `div #child ul li a img` the browser first looks after and img and than looks if it has an `a` parent that has an `li` parent and so on.